# create a list but getting a string?

Tags: python, list, debugging

```
s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""

def read_nodes(gfile):
    for line in gfile.split():
        nodes = line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',')
        for node in nodes:
            print node

print read_nodes(s)
```

I am expected to get `['A','B','C','D','E',.....'N']`, but I get `A B C D E .....N` and it's not a list. I spent a lot of time debugging, but could not find the right way.

Comment: Replace the printing in that for loop with `print nodes`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye it still not working...hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `line` you read will create a new list called nodes. You need to create a list outside this loop and store all the nodes.

```
s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""

def read_nodes(gfile):

    allNodes = []
    for line in gfile.split():
        nodes =line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',')

        for node in nodes:
            allNodes.append(node)

    return allNodes

print read_nodes(s)
```

Comment: "because the value you return from the function is the return value of the last print." What do you mean by that? It returns `None` because there's no return value at all. Python has no magic auto-return-last-expression thing.

Comment: Oh i see, maybe ive been using too much ruby lately. I will edit that out as it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""

def read_nodes(gfile):
    nodes = [line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',') for line in gfile.split()]
    nodes = [n for l in nodes for n in l]
    return nodes

print read_nodes(s) # prints: ['A','B','C','D','E',.....'N']
```

What you were doing wrong is that for each sub-list you create, your were iterating over that sub-list and printing out the contents.

The code above uses list comprehension to first iterate over the `gfile` and create a list of lists. The list is then flattened with the second line. Afterwards, the flatten list is returned.

If you still want to do it your way, Then you need a local variable to store the contents of each sub-list in, and then return that variable:

```
s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""

def read_nodes(gfile):
    all_nodes = []
    for line in gfile.split():
        nodes = line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',')
        all_nodes.extend(nodes)
    return all_nodes

print read_nodes(s)
```

Comment: I'm surprised I haven't thought of this. Good thinking using a list comprehension rather than having to a create a local variable and returning that variable.

Comment: @DrewDavis Thanks. I if I see someone using a for-loop, The first thing I try to do is see if I can make an equivalent list comprehension, because more often than not, there is one, and It makes your code look tons cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are ultimately trying to accomplish but this will print what you say you are expecting:

```
s = """
1:A,B,C,D;E,F
2:G,H;J,K
&:L,M,N
"""

def read_nodes(gfile):
    nodes = []
    for line in gfile.split():
        nodes += line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',')
    return nodes

print read_nodes(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code so that the output is
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']

```
//Code to be added
nodes_list = []

def read_nodes(gfile):

    for line in gfile.split():
        nodes =line.split(":")[1].replace(';',',').split(',')
        nodes_list.extend(nodes)
    print nodes_list

print read_nodes(s)
```

Comment: Now Indented :)